# How to remove doubleinvetedcoma in array make array on click table view Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have one table view cell and user click on table cell then multipal value add in my Array variable i know how to add in array but problem is when i am add a value in array the value 
like this `["one","two","three","somthing"]`.

i want to remove `""`. Here is my code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString * cellValue=nil;
    if (tableView==nurseTypeTable) {
        cellValue=[arrayNurseType objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"%@",cellValue);

        [_nurseArray addObject:cellValue];
        NSLog(@"%@",_nurseArray);
    } else {
        cellValue=[arraySpecialities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         NSLog(@"%@",cellValue);
        [_selectionArray addObject:cellValue];
        NSLog(@"%@",_selectionArray);
    }
}

[_nurseArray addObject:cellValue];
NSLog(@"%@",_nurseArray);
```

here is my data show like this

```
YourNurse[2337:90b] (
    " one ",
    " two ",
    "three"
)
```

How to remove `""` in my Return data  ?

please help me please share your valuable knowledge

Comment: I don't see a problem. Double quotes are to let you know it is a string. Your value didn't contain the quotes.

Comment: when i print a cellvalue that time is not a quotes  but when i print a array _nurseAray it return with quotes

Comment: As @Raptor said, it just mean that it's a string in the debugger/description.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comment, double quotes are displayed to let let you know it is a string.

Your value didn't contain the quotes. It's just the display formatting in Debug Area.